# Mongoose change name of discriminator key

Tags: inheritance, mongoose, schema, discriminator

I would like to change the schema inheritance discriminator key. This [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) says, it is `__t` 'by default', however I can find no way to change the key, e.g. to `type`.

Is there any configuration available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must have overlooked this. Example from the top of the mentioned documentation page:

```
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'kind'};

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({time: Date}, options);
var Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```